# Объясните как работает данный код на Python (Selenium)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, xpath

Что бы выбрать и кликнуть по случайному результату из поиска в Google я решил добавить в путь XPATH div переменную Url, а затем кликнуть по данной ссылке. Я не понимаю почему если я прописываю просто `Search.click()` он выдает ошибку, а с `Search[Url].click()` всё работает прекрасно.

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, executable_path="D:/WebDrivers/geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64/geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
Google = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tsf']/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")
Google.send_keys(stackoverflow + Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(5)
Url = random.randint(0, 7)
Search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='rso']/div/div/div['Url']/div/div/div[1]/a/div/cite")))
print(Url)
Search[Url].click()
driver.close()
```

Comment: Приведи полный код со всеми импортами

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Коротко:

`Search` - это список, а функции `click()` нужен конкретный объект.
`Search[Url]` - это конкретный объект взятый из списка `Search` по индексу `Url`. С ним уже `click()` будет пытаться работать.

Длинно:

В вашем коде, объект `Search` является списком (или любым другим итерируемым объектом). Это значит, что при обращении без указания индекса - `Search` (то есть просто по имени переменной) вы обращаетесь именно к списку, и соответственно можете использовать те функции которые умеют работать со списками. А вот когда вы обращаетесь к объекту с указанием индекса `Search[Url]`, вы обращаетесь к конкретному элементу в этом списке.

То есть, ваша переменная `Search`, являясь списком, содержит в себе несколько (не забывайте что список может быть пустым или с одним элементом) других элементов, к которым можно получить доступ указав их индекс. Представим, что ваша переменная содержит несколько чисел, выглядеть это будет так:

`Search = [8, 7, 6, 5]`

У каждого числа есть свой индекс, а перечисление индексов начинается с `0`, то есть первый элемент в списке будет иметь индекс `0`. А обращение к конкретному элементу будет выглядеть так:

`Search[0]` - вернёт вам число `8`, у которого в этом списке индекс `0`.

Что происходит у вас в коде:

`Search.click()` - выдаст вам ошибку из-за того, что функция `click()` не умеет работать со списком.
А вот когда вы указываете конкретный индекс через конструкцию:

```
Url = random.randint(0, 7)
Search[Url].click()
```

То функция `click()` будет работать с элементом, индекс которого вы передали в переменной `Url`.

**ДОПОЛНЕНО:**

Сначала нравоучительное вступление))) а потом объяснение))

Раз вы задаёте тот вопрос, который задаёте, даже после моего !неявного! объяснения (что-бы вы сами додумали в нужно направлении), предположу, что вы не понимаете как работает ваш "Копи-Паст" код. Давайте разбираться:

```py
Search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='rso']/div/div/div['Url']/div/div/div[1]/a/div/cite")))
```

Можно перевести так:

```
Search = Задание_Ожидать(Браузеру, 10_секунд).пока(не_будут_видны_элеменТЫ((с_таким.xPath, "//*[нужный]/нам/xpath/адрес")))
```

Особое внимание нужно обратить на слово `элеменТЫ`. В команде это слово - `elements` (окончание *-s* как бы намекает на МНОЖЕСТВЕННОЕ число).

Это значит, что вы просите браузер дождаться видимости ЭЛЕМЕНТОВ. То есть подразумеваете что их будет **несколько**, именно поэтому `Search` в итоге является списком! Вне зависимости от того, будет элемент один, их будет несколько, или элементов не будет вообще, переменная `Search` уже будет списком!

Переводя это на ваш пример, вы в `Search` получаете список из 10-ти URL из выдачи Гугла. И когда вы делаете `Search.click()` вы как бы просите ОДНОВРЕМЕННО ОТКРЫТЬ 10 ССЫЛОК В ОДНОЙ ВКЛАДКЕ. Это !ГЛУПО! и поэтому IDE вываливается с ошибкой. Поэтому вам сначала нужно выбрать 1 из 10-ти ссылок, а потом уже перейти - `Search[0].click()`

Comment: Я вас правильно понял что данная строчка `Search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located` а точнее метод `EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located` создает список для переменой `Search` и получается что `Search.click()` может работать только когда один конкретный элемент есть у переменой (т.е. в переменной отсутствует список) а когда их несколько он просто не понимает какой конкретно элемент ему брать и поэтому мы указываем конкретно какой элемент забрать из списка т.е. `Search[Url].click()`?

Comment: @goodyonz я дополнил ответ

Comment: спасибо))) что разжевывали до муки и запихали в зеленую голову))